# $.ajax doesnt fire event on IE and succeed only after page reload

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-9

Here is my code:

```
...
$('#collection_menu ul li').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  shoesApparaissent();
});

...

function shoesApparaissent() {

  $.ajax({
    async:true,
    url : hrefCollection,
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'json'
  }).success(function(data) {

console.log("data: " + data);

  }).fail(function(e, str) {

console.log(e+'\n'+str);

});
...
```

This code seem working on FF, Safari, Opera and all other navigator except IE on Windows 7 before i reload the page contains code.

When i fire a click event, the function 'shoesApparaissent()' is called and $.ajax will not fire the success or fail events (nothing appears in the console).

I am not sure what the problem is here, any ideas?

Comment: ok, try one of these: delete stop propagation. or don't use ajax inside a function, do it directly. I think that this is what making IE crazier :)

Comment: Unfortunetely the both two solution, in the same way doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What version of jQuery are you using? For this answer I'll assume you'll using a more recent version like 1.8. In jQuery 1.5+ the [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method returns an object that implements the `Promise` interface.

Instead of using the `.success()` callback (which is deprecated in jQuery 1.8) use `.done()` instead.

```javascript
$.ajax({
    url: hrefCollection,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType : 'json'
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log("data: " + data);
}).fail(function(e, str) {
    console.log(e+'\n'+str);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i try another solution : preloading all data that appear on click, and just call my object with a ID corresponding with the href (it was possible in my case). But i discover such other problems, at each step of correction, another problem appear. always callback function not call (on fadeOut for exemple)... It appear i must change all my algorithm for this case. Something must wrong.